# Chromium: has right-click functionality on download bar been removed?

Tags: windows-xp, chromium

On Linux I could right-click the download bar for options. I'm now on Windows XP SP3 with Chromium 18.0.1025.162 and it doesn't work.

Has this functionality been removed or do I have to explicitly enable it, and if so: how?

Comment: Please state which version of Chrome you are using.

Comment: Also, which operating system?

Comment: @DanD.  updated , both OS and browser version